# Parsing response from firestore not working

Tags: android, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore

Hi guys I'm trying to parse an object returned from a collection in firestore

```
val user = userSnapshot.toObject(User::class.java)
```

The user object looks like this:

```
data class User(var companyId: String = "",
                var email: String = "",
                var isActive: Boolean = false,
                var isSuperUser: Boolean = false,
                var superUserId: String = "",
                var userId: String = ""): Parcelable {

    constructor(parcel: Parcel) : this(
            parcel.readString(),
            parcel.readString(),
            parcel.readByte() != 0.toByte(),
            parcel.readByte() != 0.toByte(),
            parcel.readString(),
            parcel.readString()) {
    }

    override fun writeToParcel(parcel: Parcel, p1: Int) {
        parcel.writeString(companyId)
        parcel.writeString(email)
        parcel.writeByte(if (isActive) 1 else 0)
        parcel.writeByte(if (isSuperUser) 1 else 0)
        parcel.writeString(superUserId)
        parcel.writeString(userId)
    }

    override fun describeContents(): Int {
        return 0
    }

    companion object CREATOR : Parcelable.Creator<User> {
        override fun createFromParcel(parcel: Parcel): User {
            return User(parcel)
        }

        override fun newArray(size: Int): Array<User?> {
            return arrayOfNulls(size)
        }
    }
}
```

The weird thing is all the String fields are working but non of the Boolean fields take the value coming from the response. Honestly, I don't know why is that happening any help is greatly appreciated.

Note: Boolean from server is true and the object has false no matter what

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is the getters and setters generated by kotlin to access the boolean fields (or any field starting with the prefix *is* for that matter).
When the fields start with "**is**" the generated getters and setters are different from what it would be if the field didn't start with *is*. 
For example, your field `isActive` will have a setter `setActive` and a getter `isActive()` which confuses the serialization in firebase.

Try adding this `@field:JvmField` so those setters and getters won't be generated.

```
 @field:JvmField var isActive: Boolean = false,
 @field:JvmField var isSuperUser: Boolean = false,
```

You can also rename your fields to `Active` and `SuperUser` (without the is).

Comment: Levi - Thank you so much that did it.